# How to make sure SQL query is valid

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm fairly new to SQL and I don't really understand what constitues a valid query:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  user_id UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  additional_info JSONB,
);
```

Why is the above invalid?

Comment: It's probably due to the trailing comma after `JSONB`. But please update your question to include any relevant error messages. Also, you can use a tool like https://www.db-fiddle.com/ to share queries in a working environment, so you can see that removing the comma works when you click "Run": https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wuJj6sAx5fnMSL5wrRt7rR/0

Comment: It seems it's not, I tried it here: https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: The link you posted is for MySQL, which is different than postgresql. The db-fiddle.com link I posted should have Postgresql preselected (granted, I don't know which version of postgres you're using). Compare my link above to https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wuJj6sAx5fnMSL5wrRt7rR/1 (which has the trailing comma still) and you can see the error message about the unexpected `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add a comment as I don't have enough points

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  user_id UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  additional_info JSONB
);
```

Should work as tested on db-fiddle.com  for postgresql. As WoundedStevenJones pointed out there's a trailing comma

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  user_id UUID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  additional_info JSONB
);
```

It's probably due to the trailing **comma** `,` after JSONB.